# How to access len and pos in `StringCvt.scanString (RE.find compiledComment) input`

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, sml, smlnj

Background: 
I am trying to use regexp to parse one language's comment, whihc starts with `//`:

```
structure Main =
struct
structure RE = RegExpFn(
    structure P = AwkSyntax
    structure E = ThompsonEngine
)
val regexes = [
    ("[a-zA-z@= ]* *//.*",   fn match => ("comment", match)),
    ("[0-9]*",      fn match => ("2nd", match)),
    ("1tom|2jerry", fn match => ("3rd", match))
]
fun main () =
    let
        val input = "@=abs //sdfasdfdfa sdf as"
        val comment = "[a-zA-z@= ]* *//"
        val compiledComment = RE.compileString comment
    in
        (* #1 StringCvt.scanString (RE.match regexes) input *)
        (* #2 StringCvt.scanString (RE.find compiledComment) input *)
        (* #3 case ... of ... *)
    end

    end
```

`input` is my testcase, I hope to trim `//sdfasdfdfa sdf as` and prserve `@=abs` only.

Here are some my trials:

- let `StringCvt.scanString (RE.find compiledComment) input` be `fun main`'s return value:

---

```
- Main.main();
[autoloading]
[autoloading done]
val it = SOME (Match ({len=8,pos=0},[])) : StringCvt.cs Main.RE.match option
```

---

- let `StringCvt.scanString (RE.match regexes) input` be return value:

---

```
- Main.main();
[autoloading]
[autoloading done]
val it = SOME ("comment",Match ({len=#,pos=#},[]))
  : (string * StringCvt.cs Main.RE.match) option
```

---

The two cases tell me `StringCvt.scanString (RE.find compiledComment) input` is what I want, because its value contains `{len=8,pos=0},[])`, which can be used to trim all comments. But I am a little confused about its value and type: `val it = SOME (Match ({len=8,pos=0},[])) : StringCvt.cs Main.RE.match option`. How can I access `len` and `pos`here? Why `StringCvt.cs` and `Main.RE.match` only split by space?

After googling sml's document, I include all information I got below:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sml
StringCvt.scanString (RE.match regexes) input
val it = SOME (
        "comment"  ,           Match             ({len=#,pos=#},[]))
 :      (string    *           StringCvt.cs      Main.RE.match)
         option



StringCvt.scanString (RE.find compiledComment) input
val it = SOME (
        Match                      ({len=8,pos=0},[]))
 :      StringCvt.cs               Main.RE.match
        option



val find : regexp ->
(char,'a) StringCvt.reader -> ({pos : 'a, len : int} option MatchTree.match_tree,'a) StringCvt.reader

val scanString :
((char, cs) reader -> ('a, cs) reader) -> string -> 'a option

val match : (string * ({pos : 'a, len : int} option MatchTree.match_tree -> 'b)) list -> (char,'a) StringCvt.reader -> ('b,'a) StringCvt.reader

#+END_SRC
type cs
The abstract type of the character stream used by scanString. A value of this type represents the state of a character stream. The concrete type is left unspecified to allow implementations a choice of representations. Typically, cs will be an integer index into a string.
```

IIUC, the type of `Match` should be `StringCvt.cs`, the type of `({len=8,pos=0},[]))` and `({len=#,pos=#},[]))` should be `Main.RE.match`. Then I start to pattern match:

```
let
...
in 
case StringCvt.scanString (RE.find compiledComment) input of
            NONE => ""
         |  SOME (
                StringCvt.cs ({len = b, pos = a}, _)) => String.substring (input a b)
```

Unfortunate,

```
main.sml:23.19-23.39 Error: non-constructor applied to argument in pattern
main.sml:23.92 Error: unbound variable or constructor: a
main.sml:23.94 Error: unbound variable or constructor: b
main.sml:23.86-23.95 Error: operator is not a function [tycon mismatch]
  operator: string
  in expression:
    input <errorvar>
[autoloading failed: unable to load module(s)]
stdIn:1.2-1.11 Error: unbound structure: Main in path Main.main
```

It seems I cannot use `StringCvt.cs` for pattern because it is not constructor. Then I tried to use `wildcard`:

```
case StringCvt.scanString (RE.find compiledComment) input of
    NONE => ""
 |  SOME (_ ({len = b, pos = a}, _)) => String.substring (input a b)
```

,

```
main.sml:23.19 Error: non-constructor applied to argument in pattern
```

So, constructor for `Match` is a must here? I cannot dig into deeper any more. Do you have any ideas? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

```
case StringCvt.scanString (RE.find compiledComment) input
         of NONE => ""
          | SOME match =>
            let
                val {pos, len} = MatchTree.root match
            in
                String.substring (input, 0, pos)
            end
```